# visual studio error System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp

i am trying to connect my mysql server WITH XAMMP to a simple visual basic form on visual studio.
here's the code

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1

    Private conexion As New MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=juegos_de_la_nba1;user=root;passwords=''")
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try

            conexion.Open()

            MsgBox("la conexion ha sido exitosa")

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        Finally

            If conexion.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

                conexion.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

the thing is that this error appears [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M9Mj.png)

Comment: See [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) for how to write a MySQL connection string. I think that "user id" is a synonym for "uid" and "password" for "pwd" but I don't think that either "user" or "passwords" is valid

Comment: There's a list of attributes and synonyms [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_ConnectionString.htm) and, sure enough, yours are invalid.